# The pseudo-randomness/jumbledness of $G(n, p)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

In his original paper on pseudo-randomness, Thomason defines a graph to be $(p, \alpha)$-jumbled if, for every set of vertices $U$, $|e(U) - p\binom{|U|}{2}| \leqslant \alpha |U|$. The paper states that the random graph $G(n, p)$ is $(p, 2(np)^{1/2})$-jumbled provided $np \to \infty$ and $n(1 - p) \to \infty$ and that the constant $2$ is generous. A number of other treatise on the subject also state that $G(n, p)$ is $(p, O((np)^{1/2}))$-jumbled with the exercise left to the reader and the hint that it can be proved using standard Chernoff-type estimates on the tails of the binomial distribution followed by a union bound. I haven't been able to find a proof in the literature.

For interest I tried to do exactly as suggested using the strongest version of Chernoff I know and it almost works: the union bound works for the lower tail estimate and also if $np$ grows sufficiently quickly. However the upper tail Chernoff bound does not seem to be strong enough for $\sqrt{np} \ll |U| \ll \sqrt{n/p}$ if $np$ goes to infinity slowly.

To be concrete take $np = \log\log n$, $|U| = \sqrt{n}$, and $\alpha = 2(np)^{1/2} = 2(\log\log n)^{1/2}$. Chernoff gives:

$\mathbb{P}\bigl(e(U) > p \tbinom{|U|}{2} + \alpha |U|\bigr) \leq \exp\bigl(-\tfrac{\alpha^2 |U|^2}{\alpha |U| + 2\tbinom{|U|}{2}p}\bigr) \approx \exp(-\sqrt{n \log\log n})$.

The version of Chernoff used (that $\mathbb{P}(X - Np > a) \leq \exp\bigl(-\tfrac{a^2}{a + 2Np}\bigr)$ for $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(N, p)$) is the one that deals with both the Poisson behaviour for $a \gg Np$ and Gaussian behaviour when $a \ll Np$. The issue is that the number of sets of vertices $U$ of size $\sqrt{n}$ is $\tbinom{n}{\sqrt{n}} \approx \bigl(\tfrac{en}{\sqrt{n}}\bigr)^{\sqrt{n}} \approx \exp(\sqrt{n} \cdot \log n)$ and so a union bound is no good.

Is there some stronger version of Chernoff that works (this is the strongest version I could find in Alon-Spencer/wikipedia)? Perhaps there's a trick that avoids needing to take a union bound over all possible $U$. If possible, I would like a proof that just requires Thomason's hypotheses of $np \to \infty$ and $n(1 - p) \to \infty$.

Comment: When I try the form $$P(X>\lambda+t)\le\Bigl(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+t}\Bigr)^{\lambda+t} \Bigl(\frac{N-\lambda}{N-\lambda-t}\Bigr)^{N-\lambda-t},$$ I get something close to $\exp(-n^{1/2}\log n(\log\log n)^{1/2})$. I could have made a calculation error.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Brendan McKay, that is exactly what I needed!

Here's an argument for anyone in future trying to verify $(p,2\sqrt{np})$-jumbledness of $G(n, p)$. Let $a = 2\sqrt{np} |U|$ and $N = \binom{|U|}{2}$. Note that $e(U) \sim \operatorname{Bin}(N, p)$ and we wish to show that no $e(U)$ differs by more than $a$ from its mean.

We will need the following three forms of Chernoff: if $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(N, p)$ and $\mu = Np$, then, for all $a \geq 0$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X < \mu - a) & \leq \exp\bigl(-\tfrac{a^2}{2\mu}\bigr), \\
\mathbb{P}(X > \mu + a) & \leq \exp\bigl(-\tfrac{a^2}{a + 2\mu}\bigr), \\
\mathbb{P}(X > \mu + a) & \leq \bigl(\tfrac{e \mu}{a}\bigr)^a.
\end{align*}

The first form gives $\mathbb{P}(e(U) < Np - a) \leq e^{-4n}$ and so a union bound shows that almost surely every $U$ satisfies $e(U) \geq Np - a$.

If $|U| \geq \sqrt{n/p}$, then $a \leq 6Np$ and so the second form gives $\mathbb{P}(e(U) > Np + a) \leq e^{-n}$. Again, a union bound shows that almost surely every such $U$ satisfies $e(U) \leq Np + a$.

The third form gives $\mathbb{P}(e(U) > Np + a) \leq \bigl(\frac{e |U| \sqrt{p}}{4\sqrt{n}}\bigr)^a$. Writing $k = |U|$, and using this and $\binom{n}{k} \leq \bigl(\frac{en}{k}\bigr)^k$ gives that the probability there is some $U$ of fixed size $k \leq \sqrt{n/p}$ with $e(U) > Np + a$ is at most
\begin{equation*}
\Bigl(\frac{en}{k}\Bigr)^k \Bigl(\frac{e k \sqrt{p}}{4\sqrt{n}}\Bigr)^{2 \sqrt{np} k} \leq \bigl[e (e/4)^{2 \sqrt{np}} \cdot \sqrt{np}\bigr]^k.
\end{equation*}
Since $np \to \infty$, the expression inside the square bracket tends to zero. Also any $U$ of size at most $\sqrt{np}$ satisfies $e(U) \leq |U|^2/2 \leq Np + a$. Taking a union bound over all $\sqrt{np} \leq k \leq \sqrt{n/p}$ shows that almost surely every such $U$ satisfies $e(U) \leq Np + a$.